# Save every nth file to a new subfolder following a if statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, indexing, write.table

first of all, apologies if this question has already been addressed somewhere else but I couldn't find an answer.

In `R` I have a `for loop` that saves text (`writeLines`) to a file according to a certain condition. Every 10th written file I would like to save to a new different subfolder. In this way each subfolder will only have a maximum of 10 files.

Now, I can code a script that does that if all files were to be written (see below), but I'm not sure how to implement the change of subfolder every time a folder is full with 10 files.

The example below should clarify.

```
# generate random num
set.seed(15)
input <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 3)
# Write to file only if num is greater than threshold
thrshld <- 10
out_dir <- "~/R/tmp/Batch_Saving"

k <- 1
i <- 1
for (i in 1:length(input)) {

  if ( any(i == seq(from = 1, to = length(input), by = 10) ) ) {

    # Create a new subfolder everytime i is a multiple of 10
    sub_dir <- paste0(out_dir, "/Dir_Num_", k) 
    k <- k+1

  } 

  if ( input[i] > thrshld) {

    txt <- paste("The number", signif(input[i], 4), "is greater than", thrshld)

    # Create folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!dir.exists(sub_dir)) { dir.create(sub_dir, recursive = T) }

    # Write text to file
    writeLines(text = txt,
               con = paste0(sub_dir, "/file_", i, ".txt") )

  }

}
```

This script creates 10 folders where each as less than 10 files, but not the same number of files. One can check this quickly in the terminal like this:

```
Batch_Saving > find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "{} : $(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" file\(s\)' \;

./Dir_Num_4 :        6 file(s)
./Dir_Num_3 :        7 file(s)
./Dir_Num_2 :        4 file(s)
./Dir_Num_5 :        7 file(s)
./Dir_Num_10 :        4 file(s)
./Dir_Num_9 :        5 file(s)
./Dir_Num_7 :        3 file(s)
./Dir_Num_6 :        6 file(s)
./Dir_Num_1 :        6 file(s)
./Dir_Num_8 :        4 file(s)
```

I believe the only way to achieve this is to either read every time how many files have been written already or to somehow keep tracks of how many files have already been written and change accordingly the parameter `k`.

I believe this could also be achieved with other methods (i.e. `apply`) but for sake of learning I'd like to code this in a loop.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting the `k` loop for sub-directory creation inside the `i` loop for threshold check as shown below:

```
for (i in 1:length(input)) {
  if (input[i] > thrshld) {
    if ( k %in% seq(from = 1, to = length(input), by = 10) ) {
      # Create a new subfolder everytime i is a multiple of 10
      sub_dir <- paste0(out_dir, "/Dir_Num_", k) 
    } 
    k <- k+1
#    
    txt <- paste("The number", signif(input[i], 4), "is greater than", thrshld)
#    
    # Create folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!dir.exists(sub_dir)) { dir.create(sub_dir, recursive = T) }
    # Write text to file
    writeLines(text = txt,
               con = paste0(sub_dir, "/file_", i, ".txt") )
  }
}
```

> Results in the following output

```
> list.files("~/R/tmp", recursive = T)
 [1] "Dir_Num_1/file_1.txt"   "Dir_Num_1/file_11.txt"  "Dir_Num_1/file_13.txt"  "Dir_Num_1/file_15.txt" 
 [5] "Dir_Num_1/file_18.txt"  "Dir_Num_1/file_2.txt"   "Dir_Num_1/file_4.txt"   "Dir_Num_1/file_5.txt"  
 [9] "Dir_Num_1/file_7.txt"   "Dir_Num_1/file_8.txt"   "Dir_Num_11/file_21.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_22.txt"
[13] "Dir_Num_11/file_25.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_26.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_27.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_29.txt"
[17] "Dir_Num_11/file_30.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_32.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_33.txt" "Dir_Num_11/file_34.txt"
[21] "Dir_Num_21/file_35.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_36.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_38.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_41.txt"
[25] "Dir_Num_21/file_42.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_43.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_46.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_48.txt"
[29] "Dir_Num_21/file_49.txt" "Dir_Num_21/file_50.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_51.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_52.txt"
[33] "Dir_Num_31/file_54.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_55.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_58.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_59.txt"
[37] "Dir_Num_31/file_61.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_68.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_70.txt" "Dir_Num_31/file_75.txt"
[41] "Dir_Num_41/file_77.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_78.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_80.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_81.txt"
[45] "Dir_Num_41/file_82.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_83.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_88.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_89.txt"
[49] "Dir_Num_41/file_93.txt" "Dir_Num_41/file_94.txt" "Dir_Num_51/file_96.txt" "Dir_Num_51/file_98.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited your code a bit so that the sub folders are numbered by increasing order (+1) instead of plus +10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# generate random num
set.seed(15)
input <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 3)

# Write to file only if num is greater than threshold
thrshld <- 10
out_dir <- "~/R/tmp/Batch_Saving"

for (i in 1:length(input)) {

  # Create sub-folder if it doesn't exist
  sub_dir = paste0(out_dir, "/Dir_Num_", ceiling(i/10))
  dir.create(sub_dir, showWarnings = F)

  if ( input[i] > thrshld) {

    txt <- paste("The number", signif(input[i], 4), "is greater than", thrshld)

    # Write text to file
    writeLines(text = txt,
               con = paste0(sub_dir, "/file_", i, ".txt") )

  }

}
```

Number of files in sub-folder

```
sapply(list.dirs(), function(x)length(list.files(x)))

#            .  ./Dir_Num_1 ./Dir_Num_10  ./Dir_Num_2  ./Dir_Num_3  ./Dir_Num_4 
#           11            6            4            4            7            6 
#  ./Dir_Num_5  ./Dir_Num_6  ./Dir_Num_7  ./Dir_Num_8  ./Dir_Num_9 
#            7            6            3            4            5
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of nurandi, I added another counter `c` that counts how many times a file written and with an `if-statement` I check it that number has incremented by 10, and every time it does I create a new folder numbered with `k`.

```
# generate random num
set.seed(15)
input <- rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 3)
# Write to file only if num is greater than threshold
thrshld <- 10
out_dir <- "~/R/tmp/Batch_Saving"
k <- 1
i <- 1
c <- 1
for (i in 1:length(input)) {

  if (input[i] > thrshld) {

    txt <- paste("The number", signif(input[i], 4), "is greater than", thrshld)

    if ( c %in% seq(from = 1, to = length(input), by = 10) ) {
      # Create a new subfolder everytime c is higher than a multiple of 10
      sub_dir <- paste0(out_dir, "/Dir_Num_", k) 
      k <- k + 1
    } 

    # Create folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!dir.exists(sub_dir)) { dir.create(sub_dir, recursive = T) }
    # Write text to file
    writeLines(text = txt,
               con = paste0(sub_dir, "/file_", i, ".txt") )

    # Increase wrote files counter to +1
    c <- c + 1
  }
}
```

So that the folders are numbered in increasing order.

```
sapply(list.dirs(recursive = F), function(x) length( list.files(x) ) )

./Dir_Num_1 ./Dir_Num_2 ./Dir_Num_3 ./Dir_Num_4 
         10          10          10          10 
./Dir_Num_5 ./Dir_Num_6 
         10           2
```